How to save resposivieness with react native gifted charts?
I'm trying to make responsive chart. How do you do it? I'm trying since few hours but still on other devices like 10.9' tablet it has cutten label and chart looks a bit different. Below there is my chart.
<View
            style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: colors.primary}]}
            onLayout={(event) => setLayoutRectangle(event.nativeEvent.layout)}
        >
            {layoutRectangle ? (
                <LineChart
                    overflowBottom={0}
                    thickness={layoutRectangle.width * 0.018}
                    endOpacity1={0.4}
                    color='#007AFF'
                    curved={true}
                    height={layoutRectangle.height * 0.71}

                    //animateOnDataChange
                    animationDuration={2000}
                    onDataChangeAnimationDuration={300}
                    areaChart={true}
                    roundToDigits={format}
                    showValuesAsDataPointsText={true}
                    verticalLinesColor={colors.textLight}
                    verticalLinesStrokeDashArray={[4, 10, 0, 1]}
                    showVerticalLines={true}
                    spacing={layoutRectangle.width * 0.148}
                    data={data}
                    startFillColor={'#0095FF'}
                    endFillColor={'#fff'}
                    startOpacity={0.4}
                    disableScroll={true}
                    rulesThickness={0}
                    verticalLinesThickness={moderateScale(1)}
                    verticalLinesUptoDataPoint={true}
                    yAxisColor='transparent'
                    xAxisColor='transparent'
                    xAxisLabelTextStyle={{
                        color: colors.textLight,
                        fontSize: layoutRectangle.width * 0.04,
                        right: horizontalScale(4),
                    }}
                    xAxisTextNumberOfLines={2}
                    hideYAxisText={true}
                    onlyPositive={true}
                    yAxisSide={yAxisSides.RIGHT}
                />
</View>


You can use the below props to make the chart responsive-

adjustToWidth (boolean)
parentWidth (number)

